# Strange Tailing Number in the User-agent from iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, user-agent

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Mobile/15E148 (1234567890)

What does the the tailing number (1234567890) in the above user-agent mean?  Is it something that can be used to track someone?

I have compared it with a user-agent from Safari which look like something as follows:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1

The tailing number "(1234567890)" is replaced by "Safari/604.1".  I suspect (1234567890) means the id of some iOS app but I have no evidence.

Comment: What is the context of this question?

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I am trying to understand the network traffic and grab some traffic from an iOS device.